# How do you pass an image from the root component to a child component using state variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, variables

I'm having issues passing an image from my root component (App.js) to my child component (PokemonCard.js). I'm able to successfully pass Strings, but images never work.

The picture below shows my setup.

PICTURE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P819.png

App.js file

```
import PokemonCard from "./components/PokemonCard";

function App() {

   const [pokeName, setPokeName] = useState("");

   const [pokeImage, setPokeImage] = useState("");

   const [pokeAttack, setPokeAttack] = useState("");

   setPokeName("Bellsprout");
   setPokeImage("bellsprout.png");
   setPokeAttack("25");

   return (
       <div>
           <PokemonCard name={pokeName} image={pokeImage} attack={pokeAttack} />
       </div>
   );
```

PokemonCard.js

```
const PokemonCard = (props) => {
    return (    
        <div>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
            <img src={require (`../assets/${props.image}`)} />
            <h1>{props.attack}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

Anytime an image is passed, the entire program breaks and I'm left with a blank screen. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What's the error message? And why are you calling the state setter in the main body of the component, wouldn't it make more sense to just set the initial state instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please try do this.

```
import PokemonCard from "./components/PokemonCard";
import bellsprout from './assets/bellsprout.png"

function App() {

   const [pokeName, setPokeName] = useState("");

   const [pokeImage, setPokeImage] = useState("");

   const [pokeAttack, setPokeAttack] = useState("");

   setPokeName("Bellsprout");
   setPokeImage(bellsprout);
   setPokeAttack("25");

   return (
       <div>
           <PokemonCard name={pokeName} image={pokeImage} attack={pokeAttack} />
       </div>
   );
```

PokemonCard

```
const PokemonCard = (props) => {
    return (    
        <div>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
            <img src={props.image} />
            <h1>{props.attack}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

Comment: Tried this. While it will work to import a static image, I need a state variable in order to keep the code dynamic (when multiple pictures need to be shown).

I would have to create individual pieces of code for each picture.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `import` instead of `require` and maybe move it to a separate function:

```
const PokemonCard = (props) => {
    const { image } = props;

    const [img, setImg] = useState(); 

    useEffect(() => {
       import(`../assets/${image}`).then(img => {
           setImg(img.default);
       });
    ), [image]);
    return (    
        <div>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
            {img && <img src={img} />}
            <h1>{props.attack}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

Comment: I have to implement the logic within the App.js file. Sorry, I should have specified